# What OpenID Connect authorization flow should be used to secure Web API resources between an MVC client or its end-users?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

What is the correct way to use **IdentityServer3** and **OpenID Connect** (flow and configuration) in order to implement the following:

We have **one MVC site** `Products` and **one Web API** `Products.API`. **We must secure all Web API endpoints:**

1. Some endpoints can and should only be accessible by the MVC application on behalf of an authenticated (logged on) user.
2. Other endpoints, such as the ones used for account registration, password reset or anonymous operations, need to be authorized to the MVC client site directly, since there is no authenticated user in the picture.

We are currently using the **Hybrid Flow**, but this was mostly motivated after watching one of Dominick Baier videos. I've looked into https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c and it seems what we are looking is a combination of **Client Credential Flow** and **Resource Owner Password Credential Flow**, but I'm not sure I can even mix two flows as apparently it is not recommendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the API into a "service" type API and a "user" API and have separate auth flows but do you really need to have the 2 APIs?

Does the registration code really belong in the API? It sounds like the the MVC app (guessing that it is also your identity provider) should deal with account registration - this is normally a key separation in using Oauth2.0 : the API doesn't concern itself at all with user admin!

If you do refactor the registration functionality to sit with the identity provider / Auth server, then do you still have the need to have 2 auth flows?

If you do, you could use just the password flow and have a fake "admin" user setup in your identity system for the non-user context endpoints. Your MVC app can pass in the credentials for the "admin" user and the API can code for this specific user. It's horrible, I don't recommend it, but I've seen it work!

Comment: The situation as described was somewhat simplified. So let me use my first response to explain a bit more about our set up: We are inheriting a large legacy system consisting of several MVC web sites and various Web APIs. BEFORE, one of the MVC sites was handling the account registration/password resets/etc... but the MVC only provided the UI and all business logic was delegated to one of the APIs. This API is very large and somewhat convoluted. It's used in the context of both authenticated users and without users.

Comment: NOW, we are hosting `IdSvr3` as a separate web application with OWIN. We hoped we could "recycle" most of the APIs in their present form and just add authorization to them as described in the `IdSvr3` samples. We hoped we could keep using the MVC login/registration site. But now it seems there is a judgement call to make: if we want to follow best practices, we should probably split the user account registration/password reset logic from the user-bound resource API.